# When ActivityManager kills app, I can't restore ViewPager app with 7 tabs, all WebViews in Fragments

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a ViewPager app with 7 tabs.  All the tabs are WebViews.  The app works great until I switch away from the app.

If I switch back to the app before the ActivityManager kicks me out, it still works great.  The problem happens when I'm kicked out of memory.  It comes back, restores to the correct tab and then crashes.  I've tried removing the call to initWebView (see below).  This method restores settings like enabling the java script.  If I don't do this init on the restore, it doesn't crash but it leaves the pages blank (I'm assuming because I haven't called mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true).

Here is the code for the two files:

```
package com.mobilityinitiative.synergyworldwide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class SynergyWorldwideActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
final static private String tag = SynergyWorldwideActivity.class.getSimpleName();
ViewPager  mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
final static private int mMaxTabs = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(tag,"onCreate");

    // Set up the view pager
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mMaxTabs);

    // Set up action bar
    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    // Test for internet connectivity
    if(!isOnline())
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.internet_not_on)
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       SynergyWorldwideActivity.this.finish();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    // Creat tabs with bundled URLs
    Bundle  tab1Args=new Bundle(), tab2Args=new Bundle(), tab3Args=new Bundle(),
            tab4Args=new Bundle(), tab5Args=new Bundle(), tab6Args=new Bundle(), tab7Args=new Bundle();
    tab1Args.putString("tabURL", getString(R.string.webtab1_URL));
    tab2Args.putString("tabURL", getString(R.string.webtab2_URL));
    tab3Args.putString("tabURL", getString(R.string.webtab3_URL));
    tab4Args.putString("tabURL", getString(R.string.webtab4_URL));
    tab5Args.putString("tabURL", getString(R.string.webtab5_URL));
    tab6Args.putString("tabURL", getString(R.string.webtab6_URL));
    tab7Args.putString("tabURL", getString(R.string.webtab7_URL));

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.webtab1_name)),
            MyWebviewFragment.class, tab1Args);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.webtab2_name)),
            MyWebviewFragment.class, tab2Args);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.webtab3_name)),
            MyWebviewFragment.class, tab3Args);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.webtab4_name)),
            MyWebviewFragment.class, tab4Args);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.webtab5_name)),
            MyWebviewFragment.class, tab5Args);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.webtab6_name)),
            MyWebviewFragment.class, tab6Args);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.webtab7_name)),
            MyWebviewFragment.class, tab7Args);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.i(tag,"onCreate: savedInstanceState: tab = " + savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
    }
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onCreate *****");

}

public boolean isOnline() {
    Log.i(tag,"isOnline");

    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        Log.i(tag,"isOnline: returning true");
        return true;
    }
    Log.i(tag,"isOnline: returning false");
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.i(tag,"onSaveInstanceState: tab = " + getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onSaveInstanceState *****");
}

/**
 * TabsAdapater class
 */
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
    final static private String tag = TabsAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        Log.i(tag,"TabsAdapter: constructor");

        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = ((SherlockFragmentActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting TabsAdapter: constructor *****");
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        Log.i(tag,"addTab");

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting addTab *****");
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
        Log.i(tag,"getItemPosition");
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        //Log.i(tag,"getCount");
        int iCount = mTabs.size();
        //Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting getCount *****");
        return iCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        Log.i(tag,"getItem: " + position);
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        Fragment frag = Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting getItem: " + position + " *****");
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
    {
        //Log.i(tag,"onPageScrolled: " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position)
    {
        Log.i(tag,"onPageSelected: " + position);
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onPageSelected *****");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
    {
        //Log.i(tag,"onPageScrollStateChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        Log.i(tag,"onTabSelected: " + tab.getPosition());
        Object tabTag = tab.getTag();
        int numTabs = mTabs.size();
        for (int i=0; i<numTabs; i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tabTag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
        Log.i(tag,"***** onTabSelected: " + tab.getPosition() + " *****");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        Log.i(tag,"onTabUnselected: " +tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        Log.i(tag,"onTabRelected: " +tab.getPosition());
    }
   }
}
```

And the code for the fragment:

```
package com.mobilityinitiative.synergyworldwide;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class MyWebviewFragment extends SherlockFragment
{
final static private String tag = MyWebviewFragment.class.getSimpleName();
String mTabURL;
private WebView mWebView = null;
static final int REFRESH_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private ProgressDialog spinnerDlg;

/**
 * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(tag,"onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Tell the framework to try to keep this fragment around
    // during a configuration change.
    setRetainInstance(true);

    mTabURL = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("tabURL") : "http://www.google.com";
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onCreate: URL = " + mTabURL + " *****");
}

/**
 * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
 * instance number.
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.i(tag,"onCreateView");

    // Create view object to return
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_layout, container, false);

    // Check to see if it has been saved and restore it if true
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        Log.i(tag,"savedInstance != null in onCreateView - attempting to restore view");

        if (savedInstanceState.isEmpty())
            Log.i(tag, "Can't restore state because bundle is empty.");
        else
        {

            mWebView = ((WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webview_fragment));
            if(mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState) == null)
            {
                Log.i(tag, "Restoring state FAILED!");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i(tag, "*!*!*!*!*!*! Restoring state succeeded. *!*!*!*!*!*!");
                initWebView();
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Log.i(tag,"savedInstance == null in onCreateView - creating new webview");
        // Load web page
        mWebView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webview_fragment);
        Log.i(tag, ">>>>>> Calling initWebView on NEW tab  <<<<<");
        initWebView();
        mWebView.loadUrl(mTabURL);

    }
    Log.i(tag, "***** Exiting onCreateView *****");
    return v;
}

void initWebView()
{
    Log.i(tag, "initWebView");

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });

    // Used to be in new creation
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    Log.i(tag, "***** Exit initWebView *****");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    Log.i(tag,"onSaveInstanceState");

    if(mWebView != null)
    {
        if( mWebView.saveState(outState) == null)
            Log.i(tag,"Saving state FAILED!");
        else
            Log.i(tag, "Saving state succeeded.");
    }
    else
        Log.i(tag, "No webview to save in onSaveInstanceState");
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onSaveInstanceState *****");
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.i(tag,"onActivityCreated");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onActivityCreated *****");
}

@Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.i(tag,"onCreateOptionsMenu");

    Log.i(tag,"onCreateOptionsMenu - menu loaded: " + mTabURL);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, REFRESH_ID, 0, getString(R.string.refresh_string))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onCreateOptionsMenu *****");
}

@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i(tag,"onOptionsItemSelected");

    boolean refreshItem = false;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case REFRESH_ID:
            if(mWebView != null)
                mWebView.reload();
            refreshItem = true;

        default:
            refreshItem = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return refreshItem;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.i(tag,"onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onDestroy *****");
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    Log.i(tag,"onDestroyView");
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onDestroyView *****");
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    Log.i(tag,"onPause");
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause();
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onPause *****");
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    Log.i(tag,"onResume");
    super.onResume();
    mWebView.onResume();
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onResume *****");
}

public boolean isOnline() {
    Log.i(tag,"isOnline");

    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting isOnline: returning true *****");
        return true;
    }
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting isOnline: returning false *****");
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    Log.i(tag,"onConfigurationChanged");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.i(tag,"***** Exiting onConfigurationChanged *****");
}


public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    final private String tag = MyWebViewClient.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // YouTube video link
        Log.i(tag, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
        if (url.startsWith("http://youtu.be"))
        {
            String urlSubString = url.substring("http://youtu.be/".length());
            String newURL = String.format("http://www.youtube.com/v/%s", urlSubString);
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newURL)));
            return (true);
        }
        Log.i(tag, "***** Exiting shouldOverrideUrlLoading *****");
        return (false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        //Log.i(tag, "onPageStarted");
        if(spinnerDlg == null)
        {
            spinnerDlg = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            spinnerDlg.setMessage("Loading....");
            spinnerDlg.show();
        }
        //Log.i(tag, "***** Exiting onPageStarted *****");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        //Log.i(tag, "onPageFinished");
        if(spinnerDlg != null)
        {
            spinnerDlg.dismiss();
        }
        spinnerDlg = null;
        //Log.i(tag, "***** Exiting onPageFinished *****");
   }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.webkit.WebViewClient#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl)
    {
        Log.i(tag,"onReceivedError - Error Code: " + errorCode + "   Error Description: " + description + "    Failing URL: " + failingUrl);
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

    }
}
}
```

Like I said, I'm at a complete loss.  I'm sure that I'm either not saving the information correctly or restoring it correctly, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to look into this.

Comment: As you can see from the code, I've added logging to show when I'm exiting a method.  The reason: when the ActivityManager kicks out my app, it also kills the debugger.  So, I'm not sure where it's crashing.  Any ideas on how to keep the eclipse debugger going in spite of what ActivityManager does?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try implementing [onLowMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html#onLowMemory%28%29). I feel, this would be called before your app is closed. may be you can save the state of the app and clean it.

Comment: That would work if I knew what state I'm supposed to be saving.  I save the current tab and all open webviews.  Still, it won't restore correctly.  I know memory is going to get low eventually and so I want to save state as soon as I get the onPause method call.  Do you know what I'm missing?